# Error when creating geodataframe from lists [geographic coordinates and GRIB CRS]

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, grib, geodataframe

I'm working with meteorological data and I want to insert the grid points and also their polygon in a GeoDataFrame.
They are generated by ERA5 and in a GRIB format.

When I try to create the GeoDataFrame, it prompts the following error:

> TypeError: Input must be valid geometry objects: p_std

I did some debug and some search on the internet, but I still don't get where is wrong.
I don't know either if it is some theoretical or code mistake.

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

wkt_grib = 'GEOGCS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",DATUM["unnamed",SPHEROID["Sphere",6367470,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST]]'

#latitude | -90 a 90
lat = [i*0.01 for i in range(-9000,9001,25)]
#longitude | -180 a 179.75
long = [(i*0.01)-180 for i in range(0,36000,25)]

#the list size is 1038240 | from 0 to 1038239
lat_list = [i for i in lat for x in range(len(long))]
long_list = [x for i in range(len(lat)) for x in long]
name_list = [ str(lat_list[i])+"_"+str(long_list[i]) for i in range(len(long_list))]

p_std_list = gpd.points_from_xy(x=long_list, y=lat_list, crs=wkt_grib)
p_central_list = gpd.points_from_xy(x=[i+0.125 for i in long_list], y=[i+0.125 for i in lat_list], crs=wkt_grib)
grid_list = [Polygon([(long_list[i], lat_list[i]), \
                         (long_list[i]+0.25, lat_list[i]), \
                         (long_list[i]+0.25, lat_list[i]+0.25), \
                         (long_list[i], lat_list[i]+0.25)]) for i in range(len(long_list))]

dict_df = {'name':name_list,'lat':lat_list, 'long':long_list, 'p_std':p_std_list, 'p_central': p_central_list, 'grid':grid_list}
geodf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dict_df, crs = wkt_grib, geometry = ['p_std','p_central','grid'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last line, you're trying to set multiple geometry columns.

```py
geodf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dict_df, crs = wkt_grib, geometry = ['p_std','p_central','grid'])
```

As far as I know, a `GeoDataFrame` only has *one* geometry column. You can still have the others as full `GeoSeries` columns in the dataframe. But there can only one `geometry` column.

So you need to pick one.

```py
geodf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dict_df, crs = wkt_grib, geometry='p_std')
```

When you pass an array, the `GeoDataFrame` constructor thinks you want that array *itself* to be the `geometry` column. So for example, you could pass a list of geometry objects. A list of strings will throw an error.

From the docstring:

```
geometry : str or array (optional)
    If str, column to use as geometry. If array, will be set as 'geometry'
```

Comment: Thank you @JeremiahEngland for your answer!
I misunderstood completly the geometry concept in the GeoDataFrame constructor, my bad.
Sometimes we spend more time on silly mistakes than on serious ones.